# End date based on start date using Jquery Datepicker not working dynamically when it is called through the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, datepicker

want to set end date based on start date using Jquery Datepicker below is the code for it and works

```
 $(".startdate").datepicker({
    //dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function (dateStr) {
        debugger;
        var selectedDate = new Date(dateStr);
        var msecsInADay = 86400000;
        var dayless = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);
        var endDate = $(this).parents('tr').find('.enddate');
        //        $(endDate).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', dayless);
        $(endDate).datepicker('option', 'minDate', dayless);
    }
});
$(".enddate").datepicker({
    //dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

but its not working on dynamically when it is called using the same class while appending to a table through row inputs below is code

```
var counter = 1;
$(".add-newrow").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
     counter++;
var newRow = $('<tr><td><input type="text" name="year_name" class="form-
control"' +   counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="start_name" 
class="form-control startdate"' +
counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="end_name" class="form-
control enddate"' + counter + '"/></td></tr>');

$('.academictable').append(newRow);

});
```

HTML is this I have a table when I click add new row gets added and the date picker and everything needs to get applied to every row that gets added to table. This is an bootstrap formating.

```
<div class="row">
            <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered academictable" id="academictable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Year name</th>
                        <th>Start Date</th>
                        <th>End Date</th>
                        <th>Status</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#" class="a1">2017-2018</a></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="pickup_date" class="form-control startdate"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="dropoff_date" class="form-control enddate" onfocus="setupenddate(this);"/></td>
                        <td>Active</td>

                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#" class="a1">2018-2019</a></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="" class="form-control startdate"  /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="" class="form-control enddate" /></td>
                        <td>Active</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#" class="a1">2019-2020</a></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="" class="form-control startdate" on/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="" class="form-control enddate"/></td>
                        <td>Active</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#" class="a1">2021-2022</a></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="" class="form-control startdate" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="" class="form-control enddate"/></td>
                        <td>Active</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#" class="a1">2022-2023</a></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="" class="form-control startdate" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="" class="form-control enddate"/></td>
                        <td>Active</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row pull-right">
            <input type="button" name="add" value="Add" id="add-newrow" class="btn btn-default add-newrow" />
            <input type="reset" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
```

Comment: You should not be getting any datepicker functionality on those dynamically added elements at all - you need to initialize the datepicker on those elements _after_ they have been inserted into the DOM.

Comment: thanks for the reply @CBroe but im new to jquery could you help me how shld I initialize after the appending please, will this work out after the append

       $('input[name="start_name"]').addClass(startdate);
        $('input[name="end_name"]').addClass(enddate);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**initiate your datepicker again please check at once may it helps you better**

```
var counter = 1;
$(".add-newrow").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
     counter++;
var newRow = $('<tr><td><input type="text" name="year_name" class="form-
control"' +   counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="start_name" 
class="form-control startdate"' +
counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="end_name" class="form-
control enddate"' + counter + '"/></td></tr>');

$('.academictable').append(newRow);

$(".startdate").datepicker({
    //dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function (dateStr) {
        debugger;
        var selectedDate = new Date(dateStr);
        var msecsInADay = 86400000;
        var dayless = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);
        var endDate = $(this).parents('tr').find('.enddate');
        //        $(endDate).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', dayless);
        $(endDate).datepicker('option', 'minDate', dayless);
    }
});
$(".enddate").datepicker({
    //dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: new Date()
});


});
```

Comment: can you share html too so i can help better

Comment: given the HTML also can you look into it plz

Comment: did you include bootsrap library for datepicker..??

Comment: Yes I did jquery library as im using jquery